# object in function return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my function

```
var human = function(){
  return { id : 1,
    name : 'test',
    email : 'test'
  }    
}
```

But when I call

```
console.log(human());
```

it returned 'undefined'

What I do wrong ?

Comment: I think you have to be clearer; the above code would return an object, unless `test` is not defined, in which case you would see an error.

Comment: Actually, `console.log` is a function that always returns `undefined`, is that your issue? Or does the call actually prints in the console "undefined"?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes around `'test'`

```
var human = function(){
  return { id : 1,
    name : "test",
    email : "test"
  }    
}

console.log(human());
```

Comment: If that were the issue, it wouldn't return `undefined` though.

Comment: I'm sorry guy. I forgot to add it in this post.

In my code exactly has a quote but it didn't work anymore.